# How to setup a Websphere Liberty cluster on Kubernetes for stateful applications

Tags: kubernetes, websphere-liberty

I have a Kubernetes cluster (installed on premise), and I deployed an application based on Websphere Liberty image (from docker hub).

I configured a session affinity (or sticky session) for my service, then it can keep session via requests (access the same pod). But now, I want to keep application session when a node or pod died (for HA and using LB). Can I do that in Websphere liberty ? How to setup a Websphere liberty cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure session persistence via hazelcast or via a traditional database running inside or outside of the cluster.    This frees the application from being sensitive to scaling up/down.

https://openliberty.io/guides/sessions.html
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_session_persistence.html